# Production webpack build throw Invalid hook call error in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

I am trying to build my react project as a library.

I am using:

```
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0"
```

I have simple component with one `useState`:

```
const renderMe = () => { 
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
    return (
        <button onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>
            {value}
        </button>
    )
}
```

Webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const styleLoaders = require('./scripts/style-loaders');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        library: '',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /\.stories\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
            ...styleLoaders
        ]
    }
}
```

Build is fine, but after instaling in second project (created by `create-react-app`) I am getting an error:

> Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Without hooks everything is fine.. I am getting this error only when I use hooks.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: `renderMe` should be upper case `RenderMe` or it is not processed as React component

Comment: Thank, but it is same...